# How to solve the Fast Fourier transform

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis

I am studying algorithms about FFT and

I was practicing FFT question

question is asking

> What is the FFT of (1, 0, 0, 0)? What is the appropriate value of ω in this case? And of which sequence is (1, 0, 0, 0) the FFT?

I was reading the book for this part but i didn't really understand...

Can anyone explain the way to solve this problem ?

Comment: First, the FFT is just an algorithm for computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT). Your question seems to me more about the latter. Second, I certainly have no idea what to say about ω in this case. In the DFT as I know it, there is no room for any ω. Thirdly, I am afraid your question is a bit too vague to get a good answer here. Specific question with a definite answer stand a much better chance.

Comment: Thank!. I was preparing the midterm, and I was solving textbook question but textbook doesn't show the step to solve this problem. And , I still have no idea how to solve this problem :(

Comment: As Harald Hanche-Olsen points out, the FFT is just an algorithm for computing the DFT. Now look carefully where the DFT definition is given. What value of $N$ would you plug into that sum if you were told to evaluate that sum? What would $\omega$ be? Hint: depending on the exact formula in you book, you may find $\omega^{-kn}$ in your DFT formula, and $\omega$ defined nearby somewhere as $\exp(i2\pi/N)$, or $\omega^{kn}$ in the formula and $\omega$ defined nearby somewhere as $\exp(-i2\pi/N)$. If it is an engineering text, replace $i$ by $j$.

Comment: First consider the case that (1,0,0,0) is the FFT of $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. How do you interpret this? Recall that the premise of Fourier series is that you can write a given function/signal as a sum of sinusoids (sines and cosines). So an FFT of (1,0,0,0) is telling you that you only need a sinusoid of 0 frequency (the $k$th entry corresponds to a sinusoid of frequency $k/N$ or angular frequency $(2\pi k)/N$, where $N$ is the length of the signal and $0\le k\le N-1$).

Comment: On the other hand, how do you think about taking the FFT of $x=(1,0,0,0)$? You can think of the infinite periodic extension of the signal $(\ldots,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$, which has sharp abrupt peaks - intuitively, this is indicative of high frequency content in the signal.

Comment: To put the previous comments compactly: you didn't give the *definition* of the DFT that you're using; the result you want depends on the definition in your book. What is that definition?

Answer (score 5):

This is easy. The DFT formula is

$$X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \omega^{-nk}$$ (forward transform)
$$x_n = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X_k \omega^{nk}$$ (reverse transform)

where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/N}$ is a primitive N-th root of unity in the complex numbers. So just take $N = 4$ and you get $\omega = i$. Note that there are some variations in the above, namely with regards to the sign used: some authors may use $\omega = e^{-2\pi i/N}$.

Since the FFT just computes the DFT, we can just use this. For the first part of the question, to transform $x = (1, 0, 0, 0)$, we have

$$X_k = 1 \omega^{-0k} + 0 \omega^{-1k} + 0 \omega^{-2k} + 0 \omega^{-3k} = \omega^{0} = 1.$$

So the transformed sequence is $X = (1, 1, 1, 1)$. The other question can be answered by computing the inverse DFT of $X = (1, 0, 0, 0)$. The result is $X = (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, FFT is a fast way of computing DFT, but what is the Discrete Fourier Transfrom? Well, there are many characterizations, but there is one standard definition (you can find it e.g. on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), please also note, that some definitions scale the transform by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.):

> DFT of sequence $x_0, \ldots, x_{N-1}$ is a sequence $X_0, \ldots, X_{N-1}$ such that $$ X_n = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k \omega^{nk} $$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{N}}$ is the $N$-th root of unity ($N$ is the length of your sequence).

This might not be intuitive, so I will explain it in other words: Let the input sequence $x_0, \ldots, x_{N-1}$ represent a polynomial $P(z) = x_0 + x_1 z + x_2 z^2 + \ldots x_{N-1} z^{N-1}$. Then $X_n = P(\omega^n)$. So, DFT is nothing special, but an evaluation of polynomial of $N-1$ degree in $N$ points. Remember that the values of polynomial in $N$ different points constitute a good representation of polynomial of degree $N-1$ (e.g. there is the inverse DFT). However, the fact that makes DFT such great thing is the points at which this polynomial is evaluated: *the roots of unity*.

And from that single fact follows a lot of marvelous properties. For example this allows for efficient computation of the formula, and also for efficient inversion. Moreover it is a linear transformation (because it is a simple evaluation), and has nice properties regarding [convolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). However, there is one more property which is intrinsic to DFT: it converts [shifts to multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_shift_theorem), and for that there is a [very nice article](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/06/another-elementary-way-to-approach.html) which may help you to understand DFT. Finally there is also the "think-about-a-signal intuition" which talks about how sines and cosines in harmonic representation of your function resonate or cancel-out with the sines and cosines in DFT (that is $e^{2\pi i t} = \cos(2\pi t) + i\sin(2\pi t)$), but you can find a lot on this on the net, e.g. [here](http://techhouse.brown.edu/~dmorris/projects/tutorials/fourier_tutorial.pdf), GIYF.

Hope that helps!